# Delete certain rows if complete row contains zeros

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is an example of my problem to mark my point.

```
 Random <- sample(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"), size = 100, replace = 
 TRUE)
 Year <- sample(c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005), 100, TRUE)
 Value <- sample(c(1,2,3,4), 100, TRUE)

 data <- data.frame(Random,Year,Value)
```

So what I want to do is to remove all the rows which do not change their values during the year in the #Table1 or at least give me back just the Rows from column Random in #Table2 that do so . I marked you the rows in this example I want to delete for a better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your logic, a row should be targeted for deletion if the value never changes.  This condition can be phrased as being true when the minimum and maximum values are the same.  Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(Random=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
                 `2000`=c(1,1,0,2,2,0,3),
                 `2001`=c(0,1,0,2,3,0,3),
                 `2002`=c(2,1,0,2,0,1,3),
                 `2003`=c(1,1,0,2,0,0,3),
                 `2004`=c(4,1,0,2,1,0,3),
                 `2005`=c(5,1,0,2,1,0,3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df.target <- df[, !(names(df) %in% c("Random"))]
df[apply(df.target, 1, function(x) min(x)!=max(x)), ]

  Random X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004 X2005
1      A     1     0     2     1     4     5
5      E     2     3     0     0     1     1
6      F     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you also want to delete the rows in table 1 whose names match rows which are being removed in the second table, you may try:

```
names.rm <- df$Random[apply(df.target, 1, function(x) min(x)==max(x))]
table1[!table1$Random %in% names.rm, ]
```

Comment: @bli12blu12 I gave you code which can be used to remove the rows you want in the first table.  Just subset them off using the random values from the second table above.

Answer (score 2):

Using the dataset in the answer by @TimBiegeleisen, the following will also keep only the rows with at least one different value.

```
df[apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) any(x[-1] != x[1])), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `rowMins/rowMaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)
df[rowMins(as.matrix(df[-1])) != rowMaxs(as.matrix(df[-1])),]
```

---

Or with `pmin/pmax`

```
df[do.call(pmin, df[-1]) != do.call(pmax, df[-1]),]
#    Random X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004 X2005
#1      A     1     0     2     1     4     5
#5      E     2     3     0     0     1     1
#6      F     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to process the data in long format and then reshape wide. This is a better method because it is costly to do row-wise operations on data.frames. Here is a base R solution using a modified version of Tim's dataset.

```
reshape(dat[ave(dat$count, dat$Random, FUN=var) != 0, ],
        direction="wide", idvar="Random", timevar="year")
```

Here, `ave(dat$count, dat$Random, FUN=var)` selects values of `dat$Random` that have a non-zero variance, returning TRUE. The resulting vector is used to subset the data.frame, which is then reshaped wide into the desired format using base R's `reshape` function.

This returns

```
  Random count.2000 count.2001 count.2002 count.2003 count.2004 count.2005
1      A          1          0          2          1          4          5
5      E          2          3          0          0          1          1
6      F          0          0          1          0          0          0
```

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Random = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), year = c(2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005), count = c(1, 
1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3)),
.Names = c("Random", "year", "count"), row.names = c(NA, -42L),
 class = "data.frame")
```